# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context when using applyingFilter with CIColorMatrix filter

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, depth

I am trying to use CIColorMatrix filter on my CIImage, which is made from depthMap(I am taking photo with two cameras, so i have depth data available). I am running on error: `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`
my fragment of code:

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    photoProcessingHandler(false)
    photoDepth = photo.depthData
    if(photoDepth!.depthDataType != kCVPixelFormatType_DepthFloat32){
        photoDepth = photoDepth?.converting(toDepthDataType: kCVPixelFormatType_DepthFloat32)
    }
    if let error = error {
        print("Error capturing photo: \(error)")
    } else {
        photoData = photo.fileDataRepresentation()
    }
    if let orientation = photo.metadata[String(kCGImagePropertyOrientation)] as? UInt32{
        photoDepth = photoDepth?.applyingExifOrientation(CGImagePropertyOrientation(rawValue: orientation)!)
        let depthImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: photoDepth!.depthDataMap.normalize()
        guard let perceptualColorSpace = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB) else{
            photoDepth = nil
            return
        }
        photoDepthData = context.heifRepresentation(of: depthImage,
                                                    format: .RGBA8,
                                                    colorSpace: perceptualColorSpace,
                                                    options: [.depthImage: depthImage]))
        
        
        let b1 = -s1 * (0.9 - filterWidth / 2)
        
        var mask = depthImage.applyingFilter("CIColorMatrix", withInputParameters: [
         "inputRVector" : CIVector(x: 4.0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0),
         "inputGVector" : CIVector(x: 0, y: 4.0, z: 0, w: 0),
         "inputBVector" : CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 4.0, w: 0),
         "inputBiasVector" : CIVector(x: b1, y: b1, z: b1, w: 0)])
    }
```

.normalize() is normalizing depth data to be from 0 to 1 as CVPixelBuffer extension (as mentioned on apple's developer website)

What is the cause of that? Am I missing some parameters from applyingFilter? or maybe my CIImage is somehow wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
withInputParameters:
```

to

```
parameters:
```

(You may then have other problems depending on the type of `b1`. But at least this will get you going again.)

Comment: the problem was with the type of `b1`. That should be casted to `CGFloat`, not be a `Double`. Thanks for a clue!